# Object Content returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

Trying to get content as text, from my array of objects.

```
var array = [

    first = {
        name: 'first',
        color: 'red',
    },

    second = {
        name: 'second',
        color: 'green',
    },

    third = {
        name: 'third',
        color: 'blue',
    },
];

$('.first').text(first);
$('.second').text(second);
$('.third').text(third);
```

But instead I get:

```
[object Object]
```

Can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere, am I missing something obvious?

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/PzLjdB/?editors=1010)

Comment: What even is [object Object]?

Comment: It is what you get when an object is converted to string: `"" + {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling on JSON objects. You can grab the content within the objects using dot notation like:

[Codepen - dot notation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKPkvd?editors=1010)

```
$('.first').text(first.name + first.color);
$('.second').text(second.name + second.color);
$('.third').text(third.name + third.color);
```

---

If you really want to print out the object though, you can use `JSON.stringify()` like:

[Codepen - JSON.Stringify()](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxmOmW?editors=1010)

```
$('.first').text(JSON.stringify(first));
$('.second').text(JSON.stringify(second));
$('.third').text(JSON.stringify(third));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code will break if [`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) mode is set, because you are creating global variables implicitly.

Second, when you call the method [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) and set a value, it expects a `string` or `function` value, then, in this case the method [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is called implicitly for the objects `first, second, third` which returns `"[object Object]"`, where `Object` is the object type.

Now, the right way to create the array is:

```
var list = [
  { name: "first", color: "red" },
  { name: "second", color: "green" }
];
```

Or creating the variables:

```
var first = { name: "first", color: "red" };
var second = { name: "second", color: "green" };
var list = [first, second];
```

Now that we have the JavaScript Objects we can create the [JSON](http://json.org) string in order to pass them to the `.text()` method.

```
$(".first").text(JSON.stringify(list[0]));
// Or...
$(".first").text(JSON.stringify(first));
```

PD: You can also [override the methods `toString()` and `valueOf()`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/object-conversion) but that approach is more OOP.